# Matlab to Python code conversation - range issue

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert Matlab code to python. One particular line making it hard to understand & convert to python.

`cn = X(n*fs:(n*fs+FFT_size-1),1)`

Can anyone help me here.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that's the complete statement in MATLAB?  Its not saving the results anywhere of modifying any variables.

Comment: If `X` is an array, then this is an indexing operation. If it's a function, then it's a function call. Can't help you without knowing more. Which part of the line do you not understand?